# Building and uploading a debian package. Is a .deb already what I need?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, deb

I use Jetbrains Compose for Desktop which builds desktop applications for multi platform. I therefore built one distribution as .deb package. I'd like to upload this program now so people can download it via `apt install mytool`. I googled on how to do that and am very frustrated and overwhelmed by all the steps that are necessary to do that.

Throughout the whole reading process I wondered if the `mytool.deb` I already created is ready to upload? I never read about a .deb file and wonder if that in fact is simply the result of all the guides and I can simply skip the reading and already publish it to the repository?